# Convert String into array in java

Tags: java

Below is my Java code. I'm passing a CSV file and reading the record. I want to split the records by "," and store it into an array. I don't know how to do that. If someone can give me idea about that. I'm pretty new to Java.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class parser 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("//Users//Desktop//npi.csv"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = null;
        //String[] value = line.split(",");

        /*ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(line));
        System.out.println(list);*/
        int count = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < line.length();i++)
            {

            }
            count ++;
            System.out.println("Record Count : "+count);
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
}
```

An example of String from the CSV file

> "1234567","1","","","","ALI","DONALDSON","","DR.","","O.D.","","","","","","","","","","140-6002 SIT RD","STE
>   A","EVANSVILLE","IN","8418996408","US","6013857469","9586771232","140-6002 SIT RD","SUITE
>   A","EVANSVILLE","IN","770155917","US","6969551228","2403884068","04/13/2003","02/21/2018","","","","M","","","","","","142K01234Z","5376UD","IN","Y","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","980230944","03","IN","","WR09447","01","IN","","12532T","02","IN","GROUP","245699532","08","IN","","3HDPTO","09","IN","INDIVIDUAL","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","X","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

Comment: There is probably something good in the commented-out code...

Comment: We've redacted your data, replacing a real name, phone numbers, address, and what I can only assume where other real pieces of data, with randomly generated information. Please **never** use data with real people in there.

Answer (score 0):

Split each line using "," as delimiter like this :

```
String[] records = line.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `Arrays.asList(line)` but you should `Arrays.asList(value)`. Also commented code place inside the `while` loop.

The `List` is an interface, and `ArrayList` is an implementation. You don't need the instance type of the object to use the data. Just use an interface. Also you should know that *codding to interfaces* is a best practice in Java and one of the principles of OOP in general.

For the single line it require `List<String>` and to hold these lines you should use another list `List<List<String>>`. You can instantiate and add lists to it line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

In your code is a mistake: You are trying to split a String that is `null`. Move it into the while loop where `line` refers to an actual String object.

You want to split the string at `","`, but I guess you also want to remove `"` if it's the first or last character.

This can be done using `String.split(String regex)`:

```
String[] split = x.split("(\",\"|\\A\"|\"\\z)");
```

This regular expression matches `","` everywhere and `"` at the beginning/end of the string. The result array begins with an empty String if the input starts with a quote.

Note that it's much easier to output an array using

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(myArray) );
```

Answer (score -1):

First define a list where you would want to store all the words:

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

You don't need a `for` loop inside your `while` loop. Get rid of it and use the following method instead:

```
//Remove quotes. I think you wouldn't need them.
line = line.replace("\"", "");
//Now get the words which are separated by a comma
String[] words = line.split(",");
//Now add all the words to the main list
Collections.addAll(list, words);
```

Comment: That's not at all what the questioner wants. He wants that the string is split at every occurance of `","`. However, you are removing quotes and then splitting at `,` which might have a different result. Apart from that, it's superfluous to copy the array into a Collection.

Comment: @Aloso, Nah, I think the OP has made a typo there. I had read that statement. But it just doesn't make any sense why he would want to split the string on " ," basis.