# Why am I getting index out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I've made this code to convert whole base 10 numbers into binary. The code I believe is everything that it needs to be but I can't get  `ArrayList` to work.

I've spent a few hours on this site and other trying countless changes to no avail.

I've gotten the code to compile without errors but as soon as I run it and enter an `int` the program crashes.

**Here is the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinaryConverter {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      ArrayList<Integer> binary = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int a = in.nextInt();
      binary = binaryConverter(a);
      for (int i = binary.size(); i > -1; i = i - 1){
         System.out.print(binary.get(i));
      }
  }
  public static ArrayList<Integer> binaryConverter(Integer n) {
   ArrayList<Integer> remainder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   while (n/2 != 0) {
      remainder.add(n%2);
      n = n/2;
   }
   remainder.add(n%2);
   return remainder;
  }
}
```

These are the exceptions java throws at me when I input a number.

```
Jons-iMac:java jon$ java BinaryConverter
142

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out-of-bounds for length 8
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440)
    at BinaryConverter.main(BinaryConverter.java:16)
```

I hope this is enough information.

Comment: Don't start at `binary.size()`. Start at `binary.size() - 1`.

Comment: @Jon - as an aside, I want to point out that `ArrayList` is a choice made during implementation; you are dealing with a `List` which just-so-happens to be an ArrayList. Good practice would be to declare `List<Integer> binary = new ArrayList<>();` — _I have a List which I have chosen an ArrayList to implement._ (also using the [diamond operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) to eliminate the redundant `Integer` declaration)

Comment: @StephenP See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915912/573032) answer.

Comment: When I use List instead of ArrayList I get a "cannot find symbol" error when I compile. Would that be die to me using a text editor and cmd rather than an ide?

Comment: @Jon A text editor gone to ages. Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585362/573032) solution if you use IJ.

Comment: @Jon - as Roman mentioned, an IDE will usually do this for you ... you need to `import java.util.List;` in addition to your `import java.util.ArrayList` (I use both an IDE and a plain-text editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you `get` the value by index which is evaluated incorrectly.

> ```
>   for (int i = binary.size(); i > -1; i = i - 1){
>      System.out.print(binary.get(i));
>   }
> ```

Assignment of `binary.size()` indeed out of bounds, because indexes counted from `binary.size()` to zero, but it is out of range which is bound from zero to `binary.size()-1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = binary.size(); i > -1; i = i - 1){
```

Assuming `binary` contains 8 elements,  `i` first start with 8.  However list/array etc in Java is 0-based, so the index should be 0-7.  Of course it is going to give you error when you try to access `binary.get(8)`

Comment: This is something I should know....
That was a mega brain fart. Thanks for the help Adrian!